# Time difference in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I want my code to do two things:

1. Get datefield to give days only.
2. Get the difference btwn a depature_date and now.

Then this should be posted as:

```
2 days remaining to book.
```

I have been researching without any luck. Please help.

**Models.py**

```
from datetime import datetime; datetime.date; datetime.today; 
datetime.now

class JoinedSafaris(models.Model):
    package=models.ForeignKey(Packages)
    Location=models.CharField(max_length=15, default="location") 
    date_of_depature=models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    today=models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

PS. When i use datetime.date or datetime.day in the fields, I get an error like this:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <attribute 'day' of 'datetime.date' objects>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime.now` function returns the current datetime.

If you want to save the creation date of an instance, add the `auto_now_add` attribute to your model.

```
class JoinedSafaris(models.Model):
    package=models.ForeignKey(Packages)
    Location=models.CharField(max_length=15, default="location") 
    date_of_depature=models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    today=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```